# How use each in jquery for laravel and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

how use each in jquery ajax for laravel

```
$(document).on('click','.butmet',function(e){
    $("#meta_det").modal("show");

    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tbodymet").html('');
    var vid_id=$(this).data("id");
    var my_url = "{{route('show_meta')}}";
    $.ajax({
        data:{ 'id':vid_id} ,
        type: "POST",
        url: my_url,
        success:function(datmet){
            console.log(datmet);

    datmet.forEach(myFunction);

    function myFunction(item) {

}




             if(datmet.status==1){
                  $("#tbodymet").append(' <tr><td class="text-center">'+datmet.id+ ' </td>  <td class="text-center item_title'+datmet.id+'">'+datmet.title+'</td><td class="text-center item_des'+datmet.id+'">'+datmet.des+'</td><td class="text-center item_link'+datmet.id+'">'+datmet.link+'</td> <td class="text-center item_status'+datmet.id+'">فعال</td></tr>')
                }else{
                    $("#tbodymet").append(' <tr><td class="text-center">'+datmet.id+ ' </td>  <td class="text-center item_title'+datmet.id+'">'+datmet.title+'</td><td class="text-center item_des'+datmet.id+'">'+datmet.des+'</td><td class="text-center item_link'+datmet.id+'">'+datmet.link+'</td> <td class="text-center item_status'+datmet.id+'">غیر فعال</td></tr>')
             }
```

Comment: what is a problem with your current solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type this in your success

```
$.each(datmet, function(item){
     $(".target_place").append(datmet[item].property);
});
```